# статический импорт

Tags: java, импорт, static, variable

решил немного побаловаться статическим импортом, в смысле немного поэкспериментировать.

```
package harc61;

public class B {
    static int k=58;
}
```

..............................

```
package harc61;
import static harc61.B.k;

public class C {
    String seq = "c";
     k=8; //не распознает, пишет unknown class 'k', Identifier expected, 
          //Unexpected Token
    {k=8;} //распознает
    static {k=8;} //распознает

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        k=8; //распознает
    }
}
```

если бы и в случае static{} не распознавала, я бы смог как то предположениями себе уговаривать без дополнительного изучения данной ситуации принять результат как факт, а так в тупике Я.

ну вопрос таков:
Почему статический импорт почти во всех местах распознается, кроме того одного места?

Answer (score 0):

Это одно место - тело класса, в котором нельзя присваивать переменным другие значения.

Важно понимать разницу между присвоением и инициализацией. Когда вы присваиваете переменной другое значение, это значит, что это присвоение является частью какой-то череды команд, которые должны выполняться в строго определённом порядке.
Инициализация же переменной происходит раньше (при создании экземпляра класса, если переменная нестатическая, либо при первом обращении к классу в обратном случае), она является, грубо говоря, фундаментом для дальнейшего выполнения программы.

Тело класса служит пространством для объявления и инициализации переменных и методов, поэтому присвоение там запрещено. Для этого есть блоки инициализации, в которых, не смотря на название, можно присваивать значения.

Comment: class Water{
    int k =8;
    int p =16;
    int f =k+p;
    f=8*5; }  минутку, а почему инициализация допускается? инициализация - ведь является присвоением, так? а обьявление как бы подразумевает только это, скажем "int k;" а не "int k = 8;". Или есть какая то тонкость, которую я не вижу?

Comment: Потому что до инициализации переменной не существует, и она не может присутствовать ни в какой последовательности операций. Сейчас проверил, инициализация переменных происходит по порядку сверху вниз. В таком случае, в принципе, присвоение переменным других значений можно было бы реализовать, как в паскале, но это было бы неудобно. В яве для этого есть блоки инициализации.

Comment: https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/sozdanie-peremennyx-i-tipy-peremenny/  + данная картинка усложнили мой путь принятия вашей точки зрения https://www.wikitechy.com/tutorials/java/img/java-images/java-variable-declaration.png , судя по всему мы оба неправы, я не прав был так как думал, что только при инициализации переменной выделяется память на основе типа объявленной переменной.

Comment: Не понимаю, чего вы не понимаете. Если вы чего-то не понимаете, то переспросите.

Comment: Ок, переспрошу кратко.  Обьявление это 1) только написание "int k;"  2) только "int k = любая цифра"  3) написание и "1)" и "2)" являются обьявлением ?  если ответ "2)" или "3)"  тогда вопрос на основе первого вопроса:  Инициализация переменной не является присвоением?

Comment: Совмещение объявления с присвоением разрешается - это "синтаксический сахар" (на самом деле, под капотом, компилятор переносит все инициализации в конструкторы - то есть это равносильно тому, как если бы вы объявили поле и присвоили ему одно и тоже значение во всех конструкторах). Никакие другие операции вне блоков и методов не допускаются. Исходя из этого использовать импортированное в теле класса можно для инициализации поля (например: `private int kk = k;`, `private int[] ak = { k, 0, 8, 468 };`, `public SomeType field = someMethod(k);`)  и никак иначе.

Comment: Да, в общем, я немного перепутал в ответе, сейчас исправлю. Объявление - это `int k`, инициализация - это `int k = 8`. В принципе, `int k; k = 8` - это то же самое, но в теле класса так всё равно писать нельзя.